# Show tooltip even if there is only one candidate in company-mode

Tags: company-mode, completion

As the topic says, I don't want to see a preview, because it confuses me big time. Instead, I want to see tooltip regardless of candidates count. So I hacked it like this an it works:

```
;; I hate in place previews,
;; So I just redefine it to show tooltip even if there is only one candidate
(defun company-preview-if-just-one-frontend (COMMAND)
  (company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend COMMAND))
```

To clarify, instead of this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

I'm new to elisp, but I think there is something not right with this approach. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`company-preview-if-just-one-frontend` is one of three frontends in `company-frontends`.  To not use it, you'll need to remove it from that list and replace `company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend` with `company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend`:

```
(setq company-frontends '(company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend
                          company-echo-metadata-frontend))
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, just what I wanted! I guess I had to RTFM a bit better.